# Logo not showing when a user logs out and logs back in

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function in my App Delegate file which creates a UINavigationBar.

However, the logo doesn't show when a user logs out and logs back in if they're on the first time launching the app.

Here's the navigation button creation:

```
private func configureNavigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo-white"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    let center = (navigationController.topViewController?.view.frame.width)! / 2.0 - 44

    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: center, y: 0, width: 88, height: 44))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)


    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.navBackground
     UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().addSubview(titleView)
}
```

And here is where it is created:

```
    guard userHasViewedIntroScreen == true else {
        print("DEBUG gets to intro screen")
        defaults.userHasViewedIntroScreen = true

        if defaults.userHasViewedIntroScreen {
            print("Verfied it is set")
        }

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  IntroViewController())
        configureNavigationController(navigationController)

        return true;
    }

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  LogInViewController())
    configureNavigationController(navigationController)
```

As you can see, whether the user is a first time user or not, it should create this navigation bar up top.

However, if the user logs out, and then logs back in (where they are directed to Gmail in a Safari view controller) - this process doesn't execute again. The logo at the top of the screen is blank.

This ONLY happens if it is the first time a user has used the app (i.e. the intro condition above fires)

What about the intro condition would cause this to happen?

Comment: when the user signs out, does your code step through `configureNavigationController ` function?